# Filtering REST call with lookup field

Tags: 2013, rest, filter

We have a column defined on a custom list that allows for multiple select of values from another custom list.  The column on the list is call Panels.  When I do a REST call against this list, I can see the following:

```
"PanelsId":{"__metadata":{"type":"Collection(Edm.Int32)"},"results":[2,8]}
```

The numbers 2 and 8 correspond appropriately to the other look up list.  But is there a way that I can query the primary list for only the rows that contain the number 2 in the PanelsId field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Pete M mentioned above you cannot filter directly on a multi-value lookup. The workaround to this is to use a CAML query via an HTTP POST. This does have the overhead of having to get the request digest, if the list doesn't have a large number of items, it may be best just to use client side filtering.

```
var endPoint = "http://yourdomain/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('<your list title>')/GetItems"
var caml = "<View>";
    caml +=   "<Query>";
    caml +=      "<Where>";
    caml +=          "<Eq>";
    caml +=              "<FieldRef Name=\"MultiLookupFieldName\" LookupId=\"TRUE\"/>";
    caml +=              "<Value Type=\"LookupMulti\">"
    caml +=                 id;
    caml +=              "</Value>";
    caml +=           "</Eq>"
    caml +=        "</Where>";
    caml +=      "</Query>";
    caml += "</View>";

var requestData = { "query" :
           {"__metadata": 
              { "type": "SP.CamlQuery" }
              , "ViewXml": caml
           }
        };

$.ajax({
        url: endpoint,
        method: "POST",
        data: requestData,
        headers: {
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am getting ID instead of actual multiselect value. Any idea ?

Comment: Do you mean in the returned results? Are you using `$expand` in the query string?

Comment: I guess i got my answer. It is not possible to combine REST and CAML. I have the same issue described here https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136482/sharepoint-rest-api-using-caml-query-and-select-expand-to-get-lookup-data   To answer your question yes i tried using $expand and got this error "The $expand query is not valid for field 'Author'." and same error text just replacing Author with MultiSelectColumnName.

Comment: It appears as though I actually new that at one point... https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166501/sp2013-use-rest-with-caml-query-and-expand-lookup-column

Answer (score 1):

Even though [*query* multi-value lookup fields is not supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx#sectionSection4) as were mentioned in another answers, i assume the OP is asking about *filtering* by multi-value lookup fields.

The following examples demonstrates how to filter by multi-value lookup fields:

Assume a `Projects` list that contains `Tasks` multi-value lookup field:

```
Title        Tasks
Project A    2;8
Project B    2
Project C
```

**Example 1**

The query:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Projects')/items?$filter=TasksId eq 2
```

will return items:

```
Project A    2;8
Project B    2
```

**Example 2**

The query:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Projects')/items?$filter=TasksId eq 2 and TasksId ne 8
```

will return items:

```
Project B    2
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want but I get no results no matter what value I put in.

Comment: Hm.. is it SharePoint 2013 on-premises or online?

Comment: This solution will not work for SP on-prem, unfortunately.

Comment: @RobertKaucher Yeah, that's what I found out.  Too bad though.  Was easier to implement than the CAML query, but the CAML query does work.

Comment: Worked well for me in SharePoint Online..Instead of searching by lookup value , here we are searching by lookup id

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain, but unfortunately this is not supported:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx#sectionSection4

> Because multi-value lookup fields are returned as a string of multiple values, there is no way to query for them (for example, the equivalent of an Includes element or NotIncludes element is not supported).

Answer (score 0):

Vadim Gremyachev's answer worked for me. If the column name contains camel case then insert "/" before the case change. For example if the column name is "TasksID" then in the query put it as "Tasks/ID" and it will work fine. If "/" is not placed then you will get the following error.

```
{
"error":{
"code": "-0000234234, System.ArgumentException",
"message":{
"lang": "en-US",
"value": "Column 'TasksID' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user. "
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw some reference here that multi-value lookup is not possible
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests#sectionSection4

But when I tried same to filter post category in SharePoint online blog site it's working.

```
https://name.sharepoint.com/sites/<sitecllection>/<site>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Posts')/items?$select=Id,Title,Body,LikesCount,LikedBy/Title,LikedBy/Id,PostCategory/Title&$expand=LikedBy,PostCategory&$filter=PostCategory/Title eq '<filter value>'
```

Note: Question is for 2013 SharePoint, I tested in SharePoint online and posted here only for reference, might help other