# Sharepoint REST API - Using caml query and select/expand to get lookup data

Tags: sharepoint-addin, rest, caml-query, caml, odata

I have a Sharepoint app and I use a caml query to filter the data I get back:

```
    var caml = "<View><Query><Where><And><Contains><FieldRef Name='PublishingPageLayout' /><Value Type='URL'>" + pageLayoutName + "</Value></Contains><Neq><FieldRef Name='NewsCategory' /><Value Type='Lookup'>Memo mailer</Value></Neq></And></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy></Query></View>";
    var url = appWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('pages')/GetItems@target='" + hostWebUrl + "'";
    var requestData = '{"query": { "__metadata": { "type": "SP.CamlQuery" }, "ViewXml": "' + caml + '"}}';
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: requestData,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": formDigest,
            "Content-Type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
```

This works and I get data back. Now the issue I have is that I'm not getting any lookup data back, I only get the ID's of the lookups I want. To accomplish this I have tried using oData combined with my caml query:

```
var url = appWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('pages')/GetItems\?$select=*,Author/Title\&$expand=Author\&@target='" + hostWebUrl + "'";

var url = appWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('pages')/GetItems?$select=*,Author/Title&$expand=Author&@target='" + hostWebUrl + "'";
```

This results in a bad request error:

```
{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The $expand query is not valid for field 'Author'."}}}
```

To overcome this error I removed my caml query and tried using a get request using odata `$filter` (I need to filter by the `PublishingPageLayout` field) `$filter=substringof(PublishingPageLayout, "NewsLayout.aspx")` But again I keep getting an error:

```
The field 'PublishingPageLayout' of type 'URL' cannot be used in the query filter expression.
```

I've had a look at oData and I think it only lets you filter on specific fields?

My question is how can I use caml and odata together to get back all of my data including my lookup fields in one call?

If I can't combine them both, is there another way using the rest api to get back all my data and all my lookup data?

I don't want to make other ajax calls to get the lookup data back as I have at least 5-6 lookup fields on each item I'm querying against and I don't want to make 6 more ajax calls just to get all my data back!

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know it is **not** supported to apply `$filter` or `$select` expression for the endpoint:

```
http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/lists(listid)/getItems(query)
```

To summarize:

> CAML and OData query could not be combined.

From another hand, since [expanding of User Fields is not supported in CSOM/REST](https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/caml-and-the-client-object-model/) i would suggest to construct your query using [OData query operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Example that demonstrates how to retrieve several lookup fields (`Author` and `Editor` titles):

```
 /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('pages')/items?$select=*,Author/Title,Editor/Title&$expand=Author,Editor
```

Regarding filtering expression, `PublishingPageLayout` field cannot be used in `substringof` function since field of  type 'URL' is not supported.

But you could consider the following approach,  to filter by `ContentType` field instead as demonstrated below:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('pages')/items?$select=*,Author/Title,Editor/Title&$expand=Author,Editor&$filter=ContentTypeId eq '<contenttypeid>'
```

Comment: Thanks mate thats worked. I also need to filter the list by created date. I've tried a few things but none of them are working. Is it even possible?

Comment: Is there a way to use CAML with REST API ? What I am interested in is to get data with REST API by passing CAML. I can not use $filter because my query is complex and at the same time I do not want to return all columns so need some way so that I can request desired columns.