# SP2013 use Rest with CAML query and expand lookup column

Tags: 2013, office-365, rest, caml

I'm trying to query a sharepoint list that contains lookup columns and taxonomyfields. When I use the $expand option I can't expand taxonomyfields, but when I use a camlquery i can't expand lookup fields..

Any solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `$expand` in conjunction with a CAML query. You'll either have to construct the your filter conditions using `$filter`or you will have to have another operation that performs the action of getting your complex properties.

I'm not sure exactly what your attempting to do, but it might be ideal to create a pick list data context that use for the complex properties to be bound to in the UI.

Comment: I'm trying to show a list of listitems that contains both taxonomy and lookup columns. I want to show the Label for the taxonomy columnd and a title for the lookup column... but i'm afraid that's it's OR lookup OR taxonomy.. not both (when using the REST interface in Sharepoint Online)